# Finding the value of the element clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Material Ui for my elements and I have a button which when I click I need to know the value of it so that I can pass it through to the backend to remove it..

My JSX code

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.emails.length; i++) {
    emails.push(
       <div key={i}>
          <TextField style={textField}
              autoFocus
              floatingLabelText="EMAIL"
              type="email"
              spellCheck={false}
              autoCorrect={"off"}
              value={this.state.emails[i]}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({primaryEmail: e.target.value})}
              />
              <FlatButton
                 primary
                 label="REMOVE EMAIL"
                 className="userProfile-buttons"
                 value={this.state.emails[i]}
                 onClick={this.removeEmailHandler}
               />
         </div>
       )
     }
```

My js code

```
removeEmailHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: Can you please add what is being logged to the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your to

```
removeEmailHandler = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
}
```

So you can pass in the value in onClick

and     onClick={(value)=>this.removeEmailHandler(value) }

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need the value of the button where the `removeEmailHandler()` method is called. What you need should be in the state, given that it is been set onChange within the `TextField` component prop.

So the `removeEmailHandler()` method should basically make an API call with what is in the state to the backend.

```
removeEmailHandler = (e) => {
    // make API call with `this.state.primaryEmail`
}
```